# How to align two buttons at the bottom of the Dialog in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

Here's a mockup of the dialog I'm trying to create in Flutter:

[image: Screenshot]

Here's what I have so far:

[image: Screenshot]

I'm unable to position my two button's with rounded bottom corners at the bottom of the dialog so that it looks like in the mockup.

I was able to make those buttons fit within the Dialog width, without the stack, but then it would be positioned at the top.

Here's the code for the dialog:

```
SimpleDialog carDialog = SimpleDialog(
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6)),
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: 400,
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Positioned(
                bottom: 0,
                child: IntrinsicWidth(
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(6)),
                            color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                          ),
                          height: 45,
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                              allTranslations.text('wait_enroute').toUpperCase(),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: Fonts.appFont(context,
                                  bold: true, color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                bottomRight: Radius.circular(6)),
                            color: AppColors.action_button,
                          ),
                          height: 45,
                          child: Center(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                              child: Text(
                                allTranslations.text('new_order').toUpperCase(),
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: Fonts.appFont(context,
                                    bold: true, color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );

    showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) => carDialog);
```

Comment: see https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-layout-cheat-sheet-5363348d037e

Comment: I have, but I might have missed something, could you point me to the part that's relevant to this particular case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a working solution. It does not require the `Stack` widget, everything can be nested within a `Column` like so:

```
SimpleDialog carDialog = SimpleDialog(
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6)),
      children: <Widget>[
        Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 400,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: InkWell(
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius:
                            BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(6)),
                        color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                      ),
                      height: 45,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          allTranslations.text('wait_enroute').toUpperCase(),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: Fonts.appFont(context,
                              bold: true, color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius:
                          BorderRadius.only(bottomRight: Radius.circular(6)),
                      color: AppColors.action_button,
                    ),
                    height: 45,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                        child: Text(
                          allTranslations.text('new_order').toUpperCase(),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: Fonts.appFont(context,
                              bold: true, color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );

    showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) => carDialog);
```

The result:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You can try this replacing with Row

```
LayoutBuilder(
    builder:(BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints){
        return Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(
                            width : constraints.maxWidth/2
                            child:Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(6)),
                            color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                          ),
                          height: 45,
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                              allTranslations.text('wait_enroute').toUpperCase(),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: Fonts.appFont(context,
                                  bold: true, color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                            width : constraints.maxWidth/2
                            child:Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                bottomRight: Radius.circular(6)),
                            color: AppColors.action_button,
                          ),
                          height: 45,
                          child: Center(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                              child: Text(
                                allTranslations.text('new_order').toUpperCase(),
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: Fonts.appFont(context,
                                    bold: true, color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        ),

                    ],
        );
    }
),
```

Comment: Your code is missing a couple of commas after `width : constraints.maxWidth/2`. In spite of that it puts the buttons in desired way width wise, however it's at the top of the dialog, I was able to achieve this too.

Comment: Sorry,
I just edited that code in notepad,
If you didn't use LayoutBuilder please use it,
It provides width of parent,
And replace it with row so it will go to top of the dialog.